# failed to set up event for socket: error code 10038 in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Frequently getting this error message in postgres log - "failed to set up event for socket: error code 10038". Because of this connection attempt getting failed.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled postgres 9.6. I have included postgres.exe file in the exclude file list for antivirus scan. Is there any solutions for this.

Comment: This is basically a bug in PostGRES. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3948164/207421) for more information.

Comment: If you can reliably make this happen with a particular set of steps please report a bug to pgsql-bugs@postgresql.org with enough details for someone else to make the problem happen in a test system.